# ExtJS - Update button when editing a row call a function

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using the grid panel in ExtJS 4 and the [Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing) plugin.

I am looking for a way to call a function that I will write when the Update button is clicked after editing a row.

Is there a way to cause the standard Update button to fire a custom function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking update means, you are editing it. So, you can do it the 'edit' related events, depending on your requirement.

```
grid.on('edit', function(editor, e) {
    // call your function here
});
```

Refer
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.Editing-event-edit

Comment: It works great! I also learned that you can get column value by e.record.get('COLUMN_NAME').